# Cat breeder taught my cat to not clean his butt

Tags: cats, toilet-training

Hello fellow cats community,

I recently adopted a lovely abissinian cat. I was told by the cat breeder that this cat has been once taught to not clean his butt. I didn't really pay much attention back then, but as you all might imagine the problem has escalated quite quickly when i realized that I'll have to do this portion of his daily cleaning routine myself for the rest of his days.

I believe that he must have been returned by somebody in the past as he was kind of extremely shy and untrustful, plus he was hissing at the children whenever he heard them. I kind of feel like he was traumatized by something.

I adopted him when he was still a 6 months old small kitten, it's been 4 years since we share this amazing journey together.

I have two questions:

- why would anybody taught him to not clean himself?
- do you think that there is anything that I could to teach him back to what was once taken from his natural habit?

Appreciate your time.

Comment: I could imagine some kind of shame by the previous owner, disturbing the cat to lick the "to be hidden" parts of the body, when doing so "in public" :( good luck to you and the cat :)

Comment: i think it will be hard to change your cat`s behaviour now after four years,changing the behaviour of cats is easiest if done as soon as possible.